# Spring and MongoDB Atlas interrupt connection after 5min of inactivity

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have a little problem, i created an account on MongoDB Atlas (the cloud solution, i take a free account for "testing"), and my Spring Boot application work with a database in Atlas.(
[MongoDB Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Mb4.png)
)

Everything is alright, i start the application and it works, but if i stop sending request from my spring application during 5min, when i send one request i get an exception :

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
Prematurely reached end of stream; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream] with root cause 
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
```

I get also this exceptions :

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: rscuisine-shard-00-02-xgxgc.mongodb.net
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: rscuisine-shard-00-01-xgxgc.mongodb.net
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: rscuisine-shard-00-00-xgxgc.mongodb.net
```

After this exception, if I send a request again, it works. It's like an timeout issues...

I connect the database with this class (and an application.properties files) :

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
 public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {  

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
 private String DB;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
private String URI;

protected String getURI() {
    return URI;
}

@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(URI));
}

@Override
protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return "xx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx";
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return DB;
    }
}
```

The URI in the application.properties file is like this :

```
mongodb://XXXX:XXXX@rscuisine-shard-00-00-xgxgc.mongodb.net:27017,rscuisine-shard-00-01-xgxgc.mongodb.net:27017,rscuisine-shard-00-02-xgxgc.mongodb.net:27017/XXXX?ssl=true&replicaSet=RSCuisine-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

I check the MongoClientURI class, and there is parameter for timeout stuff, but nothing works... Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing on Atlas, but for me setting the timeout option `maxIdleTimeMS` on the connection string *does* seem to have solved the problem.

```
mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@xxx.yyy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&maxIdleTimeMS=300000
```